# iTextSharp set header in onendpage for just first page in document

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

How do you set the header to be on the first page of the document only.

As follows sets it on every page.

```
private class PDFAddHeaderTopOnly : PdfPageEventHelper
{
     public PDFAddHeaderTopOnly(string html)
     {
         this.html = html;
     }

     public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
     {
         base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
         ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
         XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(new ColumnTextElementHandler(ct), new StringReader(html));
         ct.SetSimpleColumn(document.Left, document.Top, document.Right, document.GetTop(-PDFMarginTop), 0, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
         ct.Go();
     }

     string html = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In general

If you want to do something only on the first page, simply do it as the first action after opening the document and don't try to squeeze it into the page event framework which is designed for repetitive tasks.

#### In your case

Most likely you use your `PDFAddHeaderTopOnly` class like this:

```
string html = ...;

using (Document document = new Document()) {
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
    writer.PageEvent = new PDFAddHeaderTopOnly(html);       
    document.Open();
    [Add some content to document]
}
```

If you only want the header on the first page, do something like this instead:

```
using (Document document = new Document()) {
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
    document.Open();

    // Draw first-page-only header
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(new ColumnTextElementHandler(ct), new StringReader(html));
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(document.Left, document.Top, document.Right, document.GetTop(-PDFMarginTop), 0, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    ct.Go();

    // Draw document content
    [Add some content to document]
}
```